# Extract response from facebook graphi api using ajax

Tags: ajax, facebook, api

I am trying to get the like count from facebook API. I am using the following ajax code to send the url with page name.

```
$("#get_like_count").click(function() {     
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?fields=likes",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data["likes"]);
        }

    });     
});
```

I get the following response

> {
>      "likes": 75968460,
>      "id": "40796308305"
>   }

Now, my question is how do I extract like and id values into a javascript variable? I tried to alert the data but nothing pops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JSON keys as object members, or through an array.

For example,

```
data {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

You can access `key1` and `key2` as

```
data.key1
```

or

```
data['key1']
```

As an extension, you can assign them to JS variables

```
var value1 = data.key1;
var value2 = data['key2'];
```

**Edit**:

In context to your question,

```
var likes;
$.ajax({
    //rest of the code remains the same
    success: function(data) {
        likes = data.likes;
        console.log(likes);
    }
});
```